# Echoing HTML with JQuery functions

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Say I have an HTML page where a few elements have some JQuery functions.

One of those functions calls another HTML file if an image is clicked. The called HTML file echoes some HTML to the screen. Some of this HTML has JQuery functions.

If I want those JQuery functions to work, do I have to include them on the called page, or do I only need them on the original HTML page?

If you still don't understand, hopefully this will help:

1. Page 1 has a function that calls Page 2.
2. Page 2 echoes HTML back and some elements within the HTML have JQuery functions which are already programmed on Page 1.
3. Do I have to include the actual JQuery on Page 2 as well or will it work if I just have the JQuery on Page 1?

Please help.

Comment: What you need to do will depend on how your jQuery functions have been set up. Without code it's impossible to say.

Comment: `calls another HTML file` What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use delegated event handlers for your elements when loading dynamically, i.e.

```
$(document).on("click", ".your-element-class", function(){ // or id(#)
    // code
});
```

This way, you can keep all of your `javascript` code (event handlers) in the main page and all elements loaded dynamically into the `DOM` will work.

Check jQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: What would be the alternative to make this work if the line were `$(document).ready(function() { $(".class").click(function() {`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly. I believe you load some HTML using AJAX and you want to trigger some JQuery functions on AJAX load content. If my assumption is correct you could use something like

```
$(".my-ajax-loaded-content").on("click", function(){
 //do something
});
```

Important thing is using [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (jQuery 1.7+) which bind to AJAX loaded content